# error: Cannot run program "${adb}": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: android, ant, robotium, build.xml

Here's my build file im getting error Cannot run program "${adb}": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

```
            <!-- Ant targets for Robotium testing -->
            <target name="robotium">
                <echo>Running all tests...</echo>
                <antcall target="robotium-test"/>
            </target>

            <!-- Ant targets for each Robotium test package.
            Each test-class line is done in sequence.-->
            <target name="robotium-test">
                <test-class class="com.robotium.test.testbodystretch" package="com.robotium.test"/>
            </target>



            <!-- Macro definitions for Robotium testing -->
        <macrodef name="test-class">
            <attribute name="package"/>
            <attribute name="class"/>

            <sequential>
                    <echo level="info">Running tests for @{class}</echo>
                    **<exec executable="${adb}" failonerror="false">
                    <arg line="${adb.device.arg}"/>
                    <arg value="shell"/>
                    <arg value="am"/>
                    <arg value="instrument"/>
                    <arg value="-w"/>
                    <arg value="-e"/>
                    <arg value="class"/>
                    <arg value="@{class}"/>
                    <arg value="com.robotium.test/${test.runner}"/>
                    </exec>**
                </sequential>

        </macrodef>
```

please help me to find a solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you defined the property "adb" somewhere ?

Comment: Like @bgossit said - you have to define the property abd somewhere.  And rc=2 on create process is 'can not find the process' you requested.

Comment: thanks bgossit but can you please specify where should i declare it in build.xml file or where?

Comment: It goes at the top of the build.xml - http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#properties  - the property name would be "abd" and the value should be the path to the executable you are going to execute.